# Loading Multiple JS variables up using RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, javascript, startupscript

I need to get multiple variables up into my JS code from my C# backend (ASP 2.0).  Currently I use the following code

```
    string js;
    if (swapSize == null && VMWare == null)
        js = "var stackedUnknownExemptCheck = " + stacked.ToString().ToLower() + ";";
    else if (VMWare == null)
        js = "var stackedUnknownExemptCheck = " + stacked.ToString().ToLower() + "; var swapSize = " + swapSize.ToString() + ";";
    else if (swapSize == null)
        js = "var stackedUnknownExemptCheck = " + stacked.ToString().ToLower() + "; var VMWare = " + VMWare.ToString().ToLower() + ";";
    else
        js = "var stackedUnknownExemptCheck = " + stacked.ToString().ToLower() + "; var VMWare = " + VMWare.ToString().ToLower() + "; var swapSize = " + swapSize.ToString() + ";";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", js, true);
```

However, the output always ends up just being the first variable up to the semicolon (see below).  Is there anyway to make sure all the variables get uploaded?  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var clusterMS = false;//]]> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as I don't see "clusterMS" listed in any of that javascript, I'm assuming you're never naming your javascript blocks.  The part where you're just doing "" is the name of the script, if you have other RegisterStartupScript blocks you're overwriting them each time unless they have a unique name.

Change

> Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
>   "", js, true);

to

> Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
>   "VMSwapScript", js, true);

(And give every script you're registering a unique name)